# bash script to search for device ID

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I want to have a simple script to search for a device model that has the ID of 0400. I am getting syntax error on the if line.

```
#!/bin/bash

lp=$(lspci -vvv | grep -ic "device 0400")
if [$lp -ne 2] 
then 
    echo "Card model is incorrect"
fi
```

Comment: Tip: you can install an editor plugin for [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net) to automatically have such issues identified as you type.

Answer (score 0):

Spaces around test are mandatory :

```
if [ $lp -ne 2 ]
```